# Tiny Death Star is not showing scenes or levels via menu options. Is there a way to fix this?

Tags: star-wars-tiny-death-star

I can no longer see the scenes or levels.  Also the Bitizens log is empty.  It seems to reset every time on opening; asks if I want to allow push notifications each time; plays the music even when I've set it to no music.  When the bitizens with question marks appear it shows a message (scenes opened if delivered to correct level).  It tells me I've achieved awards every time - such as the dream job achievement and having over $100,000.

Can this be fixed? If so, how?  It happened on my phone (had to reset) so started from scratch on my Nexus 7.  62 floors/85 bitizens so would rather not start over!

Comment: Have you contacted Disney support?  They might be the only ones able to help with this.

Comment: yes, happens for me too last 3-4 days, it's quite a new bug, but since no new patches were deployed, I don't know.  On the other hand, I noticed that after I built 10 service levels, and  started to appear.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, Tiny Death Star has been [discontinued](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Star_Wars:_Tiny_Death_Star):

> The game was removed from the Apple App Store and Google Play Store by Disney in October 2014.

If you are unable to workaround the bug/issue by restarting the application or your device, then there's nothing we can do: there is **no fix coming**.

If you are playing on iOS, I would not recommend uninstalling the game if you wish to keep it. Only those who had [previously downloaded the game on Android](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Star_Wars:_Tiny_Death_Star#Bugs) can still redownload & access the game.

Comment: Note: this answer is a [community-proposed solution](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/a/13064/28182) for unresolved Tiny Death Star bug questions.